# Implementing `sequenceA`

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

I implemented `sequenceA`:

```
sequenceA :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
sequenceA []     = pure []
sequenceA (x:xs) = (++) <$> (fmap (\y -> [y]) x) <*> sequenceA xs
```

I don't like the fact that I'm making a new list, and then concatenating the result via `++`.

However, I'm not sure how to make use of cons, i.e. `:`, in this function.

Please critique it.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to lift `(:)` into the applicative functor using `pure` thus getting an expression of type `f (a -> [a] -> [a])` which you can then apply using `(<*>)`. This gives you: `sequenceA (x:xs) = pure (:) <*> x <*> sequenceA xs`.

Now, the pattern `pure ... <*>` is equivalent to `... <$>` so we can rewrite the previous equation to the shorter solution:

```
sequenceA (x:xs) = (:) <$> x <*> sequenceA xs
```

This pattern can be generalized to other datatypes: see the [traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Traversable.html) typeclass. `sequenceA` can always be implemented for datatypes* by using `pure` to lift constructors and `(<*>)` to apply arguments (or induction hypotheses).

* strictly positive ones, at least

Answer (score 0):

First, `\y -> [y]` is the same thing as `Data.List.singleton`, `pure`, and `return`. `pure` would probably fit the best since you’re already using `Applicative`. The parentheses surrounding the `fmap` are also unnecessary.

Second, you can rewrite this in terms of `foldr`:

```
sequenceA :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
sequenceA = foldr (\x rest -> (++) <$> fmap pure x <*> rest) (pure [])
```

Lastly, you say you don’t want to use `++`. Fair enough. Use a [difference list](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Difference_list), then:

```
sequenceA :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
sequenceA = fmap ($ []) . foldr (\x rest -> (.) <$> fmap (:) x <*> rest) (pure id)
```